# Проверка "Пустая ли таблица?" PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Столкнулся с проблемой. Как сделать проверку "Пустая ли таблица"? Через PDO

Comment: @Alex Вы уверены что правильно понимаете, что такое PDO? У меня складывается впечатление, что не совсем.

Comment: @Ипатьев видимо я подумал, что автор хочет использовать подготовленное выражение

Comment: Любителям закрывать вопросы. Единственной причиной закрыть этот вопрос может являться уже существовующий подобный вопрос с ответом. Никаких других причин закрывать этот вопрос нет. Рекомендую перечитать правила сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 1';
$result = $pdo->query($sql);

if ( !$result->fetch() ) {
    // Пустая таблица
}

// Либо так
if ($result->rowCount() == 0) {
  // Пустая таблица
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/958771/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%9f%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-pdo#comment1602774_958774

Comment: а rowCount - бессмысленная, а, главное,  и не всегда доступная опция. так что только первый вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать `select id from table limit 1`, если вернет пустой результат, то таблица пустая

Comment: Вы не могли бы написать по подробнее о предложенном вами способе?

Comment: По ходу очередной студент, не способный сделать элементарное дз? Я угадал?

Comment: `id` в таблице может не быть. Лучше `select 1 from table limit 1`

Answer (score 0):

Понятие "таблица пуста" эквивалентно понятию "количество записей в таблице равно нулю". Следовательно, выполняем запрос

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS recordscount
FROM tablename
```

и сравниваем полученное значение единственного поля `recordscount` единственной записи возвращённого набора с нулём.

Не забываем проверить, не возникло ли в процессе выполнения запроса ошибки (таблица может быть удалена, повреждена, заблокирована, соединение с сервером может "развалиться" и т.п.).

Comment: дадад, надо пересчитать все носки в комоде чтобы понять, есть ли еще чистая пара

Comment: @Ипатьев Угу... вот только MySQL не идиот, и не станет пересчитывать записи в таблице, чтобы вернуть их количество - у него есть для этого другие средства. Достаточно, чтобы в таблице существовал хотя бы один индекс, и совсем отлично, если он уникальный, тем более первичный (и не надо думать, что MySQL будет сканить индекс - он ещё умнее).